# Product wise shipping charges

Tags: magento-1.9

I have three products that are working properly, However I would like to add shipment charges for each product separately, is there any way to display the shipment charges using magento default functionality or do I have to go for some plugin (free-plugins). Each product have different shipping charges, I have done some R&D and I tried them by using the product weight feature of table -rates in  magento. So far nothing is working, please tell me what I am missing or how this functionality can be achieved. I am open for all options except paid plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-and-product-shipping.html [tested] , once you got extension key,

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Along with finding shipping charges per product, this will help also for calculating shipping charges per category....

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $shippingCarrierTitle =  $this->getConfigData('title');
        if (!isset($shippingCarrierTitle) || $shippingCarrierTitle=='') {
            $shippingCarrierTitle = 'My Shipping Title';
        }
        $methodTitle =  $this->getConfigData('method_title');
        if (!isset($methodTitle) || $methodTitle=='') {
            $methodTitle = 'My Shipping Name';
        }
        $defaultShipping = $this->getConfigData('shipping_rate');
        //Default Shipping Rate defined in admin setting
        $shippingaction = $this->getConfigData('shipping_action');
        // shipping_action Defined in setting: product shipping or category shipping
        $qtyBasedShipping = $this->getConfigData('shippingaction_type');
        //1=>Yes multiply with qty, 0=> not depned on qty
        $finalShippingPrice = 0; //Final Shipping which implement on order
        $cartProductQty = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $orderProductQty = $item->getQty();
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
                    $productSku = $item->getProduct()->getData('sku');
                } else {
                    $productSku = $item->getSku();
                }
                $finalShippingPrice = $this->calculateshipping(
                    $shippingaction,
                    $defaultShipping,
                    $orderProductQty,
                    $qtyBasedShipping,
                    $finalShippingPrice,
                    $productSku
                );
            }
        }
        if (isset($finalShippingPrice) && $finalShippingPrice == 0) {
        } else if (isset($finalShippingPrice)
            && ($finalShippingPrice < 0 || $finalShippingPrice=='')
        ) {
            if (isset($defaultShipping) && $defaultShipping != 0) {
                if ($qtyBasedShipping == 1) {
                    //Multiply with qty of product
                    $finalShippingPrice += $defaultShipping * $cartProductQty;
                } else {
                    //Not depend on qty of product
                    $finalShippingPrice += (float)$defaultShipping;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
            $finalShippingPrice = '0.00';
        }
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($shippingCarrierTitle);
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($methodTitle);
        $method->setPrice($finalShippingPrice);
        //$method->setCost($this->getConfigData('shipping_rate'));
        $result->append($method);
        return $result;
    }
```

one more extension :  https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-6.html [not tested ]

Comment: let me edit before downvotes.....

Comment: already someone downvoted before i edit the answer , you are awesome :-)

Comment: this extension does help me to get shipping charges correctly in magento checkout menu, However  this is not displaying shipping charges in the cart.

Comment: did you checked this one : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flat-rate-shipping-per-product-6.html as in extension link, they informed it will display in cart page also, can you cross check it.....

Comment: anyone one help with latest solution -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/238570/57334